# Access Google Apps Mail

Tags: gmail, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I have to build an web-app for Google Apps market place where my app would enable Google Apps user to access and backup their Google Apps email to my server.

While I have a good knowledge with PHP and etc, with no prior knowledge to Google Apps development, I have been reading developers.google.com documentation since last couple of days and everything seems to start confusion with each-other now with SAML, Oauth2, OpenId, SSO etc, and Google Apps Mail and Gmail itself. So far, I have done helloworld app from the documentation that accesses the calendar and uses SSO for it.

I wish if you could point me to the right direction about how I should proceed to accessing the mail of the Google Apps user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you wish to use the Google Apps Marketplace, you'll want to use 2-legged OAuth 1.0 with your application. OAuth 1.0 is officially deprecated but it's still the only supported authentication method to Google Accounts for the Marketplace.

Instructions for authenticating to Gmail IMAP via 2-legged OAuth 1.0 are available at:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_protocol

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are in the right place already - if you are going through the main [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/) documentation, that's where it should be.

I have had a look through their documentation, and found this though: [Mail PHP API Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/)

A quote from the above link/documentation:

> App Engine applications can send email messages on behalf of the app's
>   administrators, and on behalf of users with Google Accounts. Apps can
>   receive email at various addresses. Apps send messages using the Mail
>   service and receive messages in the form of HTTP requests initiated by
>   App Engine and posted to the app.

More information:

- [Getting Started - Introduction - Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/introduction)
- [Tutorial - Hello, World! - Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld)
- [Installing the PHP SDK - Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/installing)

**EDIT**

As I mentioned in the comments below, after further searching, [I found this documentation for Google Data Apps APIs](https://developers.google.com/apis/gdata) which should be helpful (the page currently 404s, but I've sent off a message to Google, so hopefully it should be fixed soon).

There is also a depreciated version of `OAuth 1.0` that you could use to [authenticate Gmail with `IMAP`/`SMTP`, using standard "three-legged" or non-standard "two-legged" OAuth](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_protocol).

Comment: If I'm not wrong, Google App Engine is solely for different purpose of hosting/deploying platform (PAAS) and does not relate much to what I want. What I want to do is, develop an app for Google App Market place, that can access the Google App Email.

Anyway, thanks for the answer and references though. :)

Comment: @SushilGupta No worries. Were you talking about [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/tutorial_php?hl=en) in your questions? Also, I dound a list of [Google Data Apps APIs](https://developers.google.com/apis/gdata) but the page 404s :(

Comment: Yes, I already tried that one, but that leads me to nowhere. And the documentation that relates to gmail anyway, seems to give many confusion with IMAP, SAML, SSO etc which says different things in different places.